# order by semester term in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

i have semester term values such as fall 2011, spring 2011 and so on.
I want the result to be order in sequential manner 
example

```
fall 2001
spring 2001
fall 2002
spring 2002
....
```

however I am getting

```
fall 2001
fall 2002
.....
spring 2001
spring 2002
.....
```

when doing `order by semester`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Semester 
FROM Table
ORDER BY regexp_replace(Semester, '[^0-9]+', ''),
         regexp_replace(Semester, '[^a-zA-Z]+', '')
```

This parses out the numbers from the text so you can first order by Year, then by the text.

Or you could just get the right 4 most characters and order by them first...
Assming the right 4 most characters will always be the year...

```
SELECT Semester
FROM Table
ORDER BY substr('spring 2001',-4), semester
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE expression in your ORDER BY:

```
SELECT SEMESTER, whatever
  FROM SEMESTER_VALUES
  ORDER BY CASE SEMESTER
             WHEN 'spring 2001' THEN 1
             WHEN 'fall 2001'   THEN 2
             WHEN 'spring 2002' THEN 3
             WHEN 'fall 2002'   THEN 4
             WHEN 'spring 2003' THEN 5
             WHEN 'fall 2003'   THEN 6
             WHEN 'spring 2004' THEN 7
             WHEN 'fall 2004'   THEN 8
             WHEN 'spring 2005' THEN 9
             WHEN 'fall 2005'   THEN 10
           END;
```

You can make the CASE expression as arbitrarily complex as you need.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible solutions.  If you are able to modify the table, I would add a date field representing the end date of each semester.  Then you can order by the date to get the desired order.